# A way to solve the recurrence relation $T_i = T_{i-1} + 2 T_{i-2} + 2^{i - 2} - (i - 2)^2$

Tags: recurrence-relations

Given the recurrence relation
$$
T_i = T_{i-1} + 2 T_{i-2} + 2^{i - 2} - (i - 2)^2,\quad
 T_0 = 0,\quad T_1 = 1.
$$

I need to solve it. I tried to solve the relation using generating function, but eventually I came to system of linear equations with dimension $6$.

Maybe I have to use another way to solve the relation

Comment: If you want I can share my calculations/

Comment: Try solving the homogeneous part and combining with a particular solution.

Comment: @Macavity Do I want to guess a particular solution?

Comment: Guesswork is not needed for the functions you have. Polynomial and exponentially are handled systematically - for e.g by the method of undetermined coefficients. On a mobile so don't want to write much now, but you should be able to find on the net.

Comment: Here is one way http://www.cwu.edu/~curtiswd/Math330-Spr13/Handouts/Handout-20-MethodOfUndeterminedCoefficients.pdf

Comment: @Macavity. I've solved the homegeneous part. Now can I substitute it into the original relation to find a particular solution?

Comment: Dimension 6 is to be expected, actually: 2 for the 2-term explicit recurrence, another 1 for the exponential additive term, and 2+1 for the degree-2 polynomial term. So I think you're on the right track. If you're looking for roots of a characteristic polynomial of degree 6, one of them will be 2 (from the exponential term) and three of them will be 1 (from the polynomial term), if that helps.

Comment: Nope. You will have to assume a form for the particular solution, find it.  Check the note I gave the link for. You can find particular solutions for each term and add them to the homogeneous solution in the end.

Comment: do you exspect a simple form?

Comment: @Macavity Does the particular solution looks like following: $T′_i=A2^i+Bi^2+Ci + D$

Answer (score 1):

The roots of the characteristic polynomial of the homogeneous part are $2$ and $-1$. To this list, we need to add $2$ again (from the exponential part of the recurrence) and $1$ three times (from the polynomial part of degree $2$). This means that the general form of the solution will be
$$
T_i = (ai^2+bi+c)+(di+e)2^i+f(-1)^i
$$
for some constants $a,b,c,d,e,f$. Using the first six values and solving the resulting system of linear equations yields the formula
$$
T_i = \frac{i^2+i+2}{2} +\frac{3 i-14}{9} 2^{i-1} -\frac{2 }{9}(-1)^i.
$$
The generating function method should work equally well and lead to the same solution.

Comment: I can't understand how we obtained the general form.
$T_i = T^h_i + T^p_i$. And $T^h_i = C_1 2^i + C_2 (-1)^i$ .
But I think that $T^p_i  = a 2^i + bi^2 + ci  + d$

Comment: In the other words why the coefficient of $2^i$ is $(di + e)$ in your solution?

Comment: I understand. It depends on roots of characteristic polynomial.